# Bake Diffuse texture color wrong shades

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm still fairly new to Nodes/texturing.
Had it baking correctly until I Appended the material into another model that needed the same treatment. Realized I had changed and saved some of the node settings (color/color ramp) so I copied the 2nd model back to the original to bake. The mask baked fine but the 2nd bake has 3 tones of red??? I thought it may have some thing to do with the 2nd model using a different 'Ray Distance' as I baked the normal on 2.7(I think) and have only recently started using 2.9(new PC), but I have 'Selected to active' turned off.
[image: Text]
Spent about 3hrs trying to fix this and have finally given up. I Appended it to a cube if anyone can take a look. https://pasteall.org/blend/d49a6e9cc5fd4d99b17f96c2769369a3

Answer (score 0):

After a heap of testing to every part of my nodes I eventually found one of my Normal Maps was plugged into my Color ramp. Not sure how I did it but that just killed a day of work (took a day off due to extreme frustration towards myself).